# My yathzee function stucks in the if statement

Tags: r

I just started to learn R and I am asked to write a function for a simplified Yahtzee game. The objective of the game is to score points by rolling five dice to make certain combinations.

There are 6 different categories:
If all five dice the same, the player gets 50 points (Yahtzee).
Five sequential dices (i.e, all unique dices) yields 40 points (Straight)
Three of one number and two of another yields 25 points.
If four dices are the same, it gives a score of the sum of all dices.
If three dices are the same, it gives a score of the sum of all dices.
Any remaining condition gives a score of the sum of all dices.

Here is how I have tried (Although I think that the last three categories can be condensed into the same logical test):

```
yahtzee <- function(){

dices <- sample(1:6,5,TRUE)

t <- table(dices)

t.x <- unname(t)


if(length(unique(dices) == 1)){

print("Yahtzee")

score <- 50

} 
else if(dices == c(1,2,3,4,5) | dices == c(2,3,4,5,6)){

print("Straight")

score <- 40

} 
else if(t.x[1] == 3 & t.x[2] == 2 | t.x[1] == 2 & t.x[2] == 3){

print("Full House")

score <- 25

} 
else if(t.x[1] == 4 & t.x[2] == 1 | t.x[1] == 1 & t.x[2] == 4){

print("Four Of A Kind")

score <- sum(dices)

} 
else if(t.x[1] == 3 & t.x[2] == 1 & t.x[3] == 1 | t.x[1] == 1 & t.x[2] == 3 & t.x[3] == 1 | t.x[1] == 1 & t.x[2] == 1 & t.x[3] == 3){

print("Three Of A Kind")

score <- sum(dices)

} 
else{

print("Chance")

score <- sum(dices)

}

print(dices)

print(score)

}
```

When I run the function, I always earn 50 points and 'Yahtzee' occurs no matter what the dice combination is. My code does not go over the remaining else if statements or somehow stucks in the first line. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You basically just had a couple parens mismatched. I don't think you need `t.x` and can just leverage properties of `t` combined with the `any` function. Here's how I'd rewrite your function:

```
yahtzee <- function(){

  dices <- sample(1:6,5,TRUE)
  t <- table(dices)


  if(length(unique(dices)) == 1){
    print("Yahtzee")
    score <- 50
  } 
  else if(length(unique(dices)) == 5){
    print("Straight")
    score <- 40
  } 
  else if(any(t == 3) * any(t == 2)){
    print("Full House")
    score <- 25
  }
  else if(any(t == 4)){
    print("Four Of A Kind")
    score <- sum(dices)

  } 
  else if(any(t == 3)){
    print("Three Of A Kind")
    score <- sum(dices)

  } 
  else{
    print("Chance")
    score <- sum(dices)
  }

  print(dices)
  print(score)
}


yahtzee()
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. The only thing that I can ask is that what does the " * " sign in any(t == 3) * any(t == 2) mean? I was not aware of writing that if-statement with " * ".

Comment: @e.erhan - you can extract that code and run it by itself...the `*` is multiplication and `any()` returns `TRUE/FALSE` values, so in this instance, it is saying "any t values equal 3 AND any t values = 2"

Answer (score 0):

```
yahtzee <- function () {
    dices <- sample(1:6, 5, TRUE)

    if( length(unique(dices)) == 1 ) {
        print("Yahtzee")
        score <- 50

    } else if ( length(unique(dices)) == 5 ) {
        print("Straight")
        score <- 40

    } else if ( length(unique(dices)) == 2 && length(which(dices == 
        unique(dices)[1])) == 2 ||
            length(which(dices == unique(dices)[2])) == 2 ) {
        print("Full House")
        score <- 25

     } else if ( length(unique(dices)) == 2 && length(which(dices == 
         unique(dices)[1])) == 1 ||
            length(which(dices == unique(dices)[2])) == 1 ) {
        print("Four Of A Kind")
        score <- sum(dices)

    } else if ( length(unique(dices)) == 3 && length(which(dices == 
        unique(dices)[1])) == 3 ||
            length(which(dices == unique(dices)[2])) == 3 ||
            length(which(dices == unique(dices)[3])) == 3 ) {
        print("Three Of A Kind")
        score <- sum(dices)

    } else {
        print("Chance")
        score <- sum(dices)

    }
    print(dices)
    print(score)

}
```